# django channels: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established

Tags: django, websocket, django-channels

I am pretty new in django channels. I read [this tutorial](https://gearheart.io/blog/creating-a-chat-with-django-channels/) to create a realtime chat application, but I have this error

**in Chrome:**

`WebSocket connection to 'ws://127.0.0.1:8000/chat/stream/' failed: WebSocket is 
closed before the connection is established.`

**in Firefox:**

`Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at ws://127.0.0.1:8001/chat/stream/.`

`The connection to ws://127.0.0.1:8001/chat/stream/ was interrupted while the page was loading.`

Please help me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: please show us the code. Best to start with consumers and routing.

Answer (score 0):

You may miss this in your code:

```
message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})
```

in `ws_connect`